can't get doit task to accept parameters from command line
the command:
doit -f ./srvapp/doit-build.py build --stype $argc_type --zone $argc_zone
the DAG
def task_build():
    """build"""

    def python_build(stype, zone):
        print(f"TYPE: {stype}, ZONE: {zone}")

    return {
        'actions': [python_build],
        'verbosity':2,
        'params':[
            {'name':'zone', 'default': 'BLANKZONE'},
            {'name':'stype', 'default': 'BLANKSTYPE'}
        ]
        }

the result:
TYPE: email-sifter
ZONE: uat
ACTION: build
ERROR: Error parsing Task: option --stype not recognized (parsing options: [CmdOption({'name':'zone', 'short':'','long':'' }), CmdOption({'name':'stype', 'short':'','long':'' })]). Got: ['--stype', 'email-sifter', '--zone', 'uat']

Not sure why its telling me style not recognized?
Following doc from here:  https://pydoit.org/task-args.html#task-action-parameters

Try changing params to: {'name':'zone', 'long':'zone', 'default': 'BLANKZONE'}, {'name':'stype', 'long':'stype', 'default': 'BLANKSTYPE'}.

@user202311 that worked, thanks.  This doc seems inaccurate: Each parameter must define a name, and a default value. It can optionally define a “short” and “long”.
